# Using svn and .NET Winforms - Building Install Files Deletes _svn Folders

Tags: .net, vb.net, svn, version-control

Does anyone know how to build an install project without it deleting/overwriting the _svn folders?

I have a VB .NET 2005 Winform Application and each time I do an Installer Build, it deletes/overwrites the _svn folder in the directories.  How can I stop this from happening?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks!
JFV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never had a problem with this using Vis Studio 2005

Have you tried using .svn folders rather than _svn?

If you are using TortoiseSVN there is an option to change it in the settings.